# Visual Studio 2012 hangs when opening site.master

Tags: visual-studio-2012, webforms

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate 11.0.60315.01 Update 2 under Windows 7 Pro. I have been doing some non visual development with it for a while with no issues. I have just now created a fresh web forms application. As soon as I go to open the Site.master in "Design View" in the HTML editor  VS freezes.

The freee results in me being unable to click elsewhere in the IDE (Menu's, Solution Explorer) etc. so it does not look as if the IDE has hung, rather that it has just stopped responding. The same behaviour is evident if I run devenv.exe /SafeMode. CPU usage is minimal and I have plenty of RAM available.

Any suggestions on how I diagnose and resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Running VS as administrator seems to alleviate the problem.